# Is there an option (or a set of patches) to make Redis selectively read-only?

Tags: redis

I would love to have a means to restrict read/write access to a Redis server to a select list of clients.  For this purpose AUTH and passwords would not be sufficient.  The purpose would be to allow a large number of readers on one side of a Redis server or cluster to fetch/get values while only allowing a smaller number of systems to post new data thereto.

Does anyone know of a set of patches to do this?  Perhaps some "undocumented" or obscure configuration option?  An alternative to Redis which provides similar data structures, operations and synchronization/atomicity features but also offers this?

What would be the best way to suggest this as an enhancement request to Salvatore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webdis - 'A fast HTTP interface for Redis' - supports access control.  It provides a REST/JSON API to redis and supports per-command access control by http auth or IP range.

http://webd.is/

Answer (score 1):

Redis is all about simplicity so I doubt such a prominent feature would be undocumented. If you want to contribute, checkout the [community page](http://redis.io/community). It's worth a try, but they are very clear that they want to keep Redis simple and that you will find resistance to new features.